# How to get the route matched position of a coordinate?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I'm wondering how to get the closest route position for a given (lat,lon).

I found it's possible to get it by using H.service.RoutingService.calculateRoute. The waypoints are mappedMatched and I can get the position in the result object :

```
result.response.route[0].waypoint[i].mappedPosition
```

Is there a better way ? (it's a little hardcore to compute a route only for this purpose)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to get something similar (possibly the same) when you reverse geocode your location. If the match is good enough the response has a 'navigationPosition' (which, I believe to be the point you would drive/navigate to to access this location).

From the JSAPI you can use [H.service.GeocodingService#reversGeocode](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-service-geocodingservice.html#h-service-geocodingservice__reversegeocode) to access the Geocoder API from JavaScript.

Here's a REST example you can try: https://developer.here.com/api-explorer/rest/geocoder/reverse-geocode

See Response.View[0].Result[0].Location.NavigationPosition

```js
{
  "Response": {
    "MetaInfo": {
      ...
    },
    "View": [
      {
        ...
        "Result": [
          {
            ...
            "Location": {
              ...
              "DisplayPosition": {
                "Latitude": 41.88403,
                "Longitude": -87.63881
              },
              "NavigationPosition": [
                {
                  "Latitude": 41.88425,
                  "Longitude": -87.63845
                }
              ],
              ...
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it's not the same; the "reverse geocoding approach" is worse than the "routing approach". I did a benchmark test with arbitrary positions and most of the time there is less than 1 meter difference between the two. However in some cases I got up to 50 meters difference in favor of the routing approach. Thanks for the suggestion.